# Signal extraction

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-detection

I have a receiver which receives several signals. The different signals are summed to the receiver.

How can we find a signal in this sum? I know we can use PN (pseudo-random noise) codes but I do not want to do that. I am looking for a method that does not change the size of the transmitter signals.

Comment: Not enough information on those signals ... Answering is impossible

Answer (score 2):

You cannot... without further assumptions or extending the size of signals. Let us give a simple counter-example with  1-sample signals: $s_1$, $s_2$ and $s_3$ sum to $s=10$? What are they? There is an infinity of valid answers.

However, you could, with filtering, source separation, whether informed or blind, or constrained unmixing, which provide means to separating signals, albeit with additional assumptions (numerosity, support, orthogonality, independence, sparsity, positivity, etc.), without specific data encoding.

Additional information is required to unmix your question.